# Functions that Search for Items

Tags: function, common-lisp, built-in

There are a number of sequence (and also list) functions in Common Lisp that search a given sequence or list with respect to an item. For example, `(position item sequence)` searches the given sequence for an element matching the item. Some other sequence searching functions taking an item include `find`, `count`, `delete`, and `remove`. Similar list searching functions include `pushnew`, `member`, `adjoin`, `assoc`, and `rassoc`.

In each case only one item is searched for at a time. But if you want to search for multiple items using these handy built-in functions, the easiest way is probably to put the function in a loop for each item. The drawback is that the sequence or list will be newly scanned for each item.

You can write your own function to scan the sequence or list once for all items, but this seems like it is more-or-less duplicating the effort that went into designing the built-in functions in the first place. I'm wondering why these functions were not designed at a higher level of abstraction to take multiple items? Wouldn't the default performance (and results)  with one item be the same?

Comment: That's why you have :start parameters (mainly for vectors); The member function with lists allows you to have acces to the remaining elements. Or you can use remove to collect multiple elements which accepts the same parameters as find etc. The only case where you have to use a loop is if you want to collect all positions in a list efficiently. From those you can always build higher-level functions or use libraries.

Comment: Right. I guess a better way to look at this is that most of the "item" functions offer `-if` variations with a predicate (or :test). You can then pick out the items you want in the predicate with one scan. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`-if` and `-if-not`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/17_bb.htm) versions of search functions.
E.g., to find all teenagers in your database, you could do

```
(remove-if-not (lambda (age) (<= 13 age 19)) people :key #'person-age)
```